# Sharing a routine between view controllers

Tags: ios

I have an app where I have a long routine to draw out a pdf document. I need to access this from a number of view controllers but I am not sure how. As the moment the code is copied into each of the VC's .m file which I know is ridiculous. One of the problems is that each VC has a large number of variables that need to be sent to the MakePdf routine and sending data between VCs appears to be problematic (or at least that is what I am beginning to understand).

Any pointers?

This is what I would like:

[image]

Comment: Do you need every data from every VCs at the time of PDF creating? Or create a PDF per VC?

Answer (score 3):

You should make a class, with a singleton methods (like "+sharedObject") with all the code.
Then you access it with this code :

```
[[MyClass sharedObject] mySharedMethodForPdf];
```

http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/

Comment: Thanks - I have just started to do that but can I put the variable name from VC1 in the shared class so that when it is accessed from VC1 it is included? Or do I need to send the variable to the shared class?

Comment: I think you have to put all the logic related to pdf in the shared object, and give it the dynamic data throught the method.

Answer (score 3):

You could make all your view controllers that need access to this method (and any others) a subclass of a class which implements this function. They would then all inherit the make pdf code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definietly create an abstract **UIViewController class that holds the common characteristics**, or a protocol at least, something like `<PDFMakerDataSource>`.

The `PDFMaker` singleton could be fine, define an **`activeViewController` property on PDFMaker**.
So when the VC appears, I'd set that property, then you can call make on PDFMaker, that will use the currently bound VC as data source.

---

Anyway, why singletons? **Why don't just create a PDFMaker object?** You can create it with every VC, so every VC should have an instance of it.

Something like:

```
@interface PDFMaker : NSObject

+(id)pdfMakerWithDataSource:(id<PDFMakerDataSource>) dataSource;
-(void)makePDFwithCompletion:(void(^)(id PDF)) completionBlock;

@end
```

And the data source, like:

```
@protocol PDFMakerDataSource <NSObject>
@optional
-(NSString*)fileName;
-(UIImage*)coverImage;
-(NSString*)whateverData;
@end
```

So in every VC of the world can be now **PDFMaker compilant**, like:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <PDFMakerDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) PDFMaker *pdfMaker;
@end

@implementation SomeViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pdfMake = [PDFMaker pdfMakerWithDataSource:self];
}


// PDFMaker data source implementation (bind to UI for example)

-(NSString*)fileName
{ return self.fileNameTextField.text; }

-(NSString*)coverImage
{ return self.coverImageView.image; }

...

// Make That PDF

-(IBAction)makePDF
{
    [self.pdfMaker makePDFwithCompletion:^(id PDF)
    { NSLog(@"Shiny PDF just made: %@", PDF); }
}

@end
```